# Where does QGIS store the list of server connections (WFS)?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, wfs

Over time I have collected a bit of a list of WFS server addresses. I would like to include the list of server connections in my overall backup. Therefore, I like to know where QGIS stores the list.

[image: Data Source Manager | WFS]

Comment: On Windows it uses (or used to use ~ haven't checked recently) the registry.  On my Linux I can see some remnant connection details for QGIS 2 /home/USER/.config/QGIS/QGIS2.conf but can't find similar settings for QGIS 3

Comment: Try `/home/USER/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/YOUR-PROFILE/QGIS/QGIS3.ini` on Linux

Comment: @nmtoken Perfect. I am using Ubuntu. Thank you. Feel free to post your comment as a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For QGIS 2 on Windows it uses the registry.

For QGIS 2 on Linux (Mint) I can see some remnant connection details for QGIS 2 at:

```
/home/USER/.config/QGIS/QGIS2.conf
```

For QGIS 3 on Linux (Mint) I found the WFS settings at:

```
/home/USER/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/YOUR-PROFILE/QGIS/QGIS3.ini
```

Answer (score 2):

For windows 10, QGIS 3 you can find the settings in :

```
"C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\QGIS3.ini"
```

In case you are planning to clean install your windows and preserve your settings (including plugins), you need to back up this folder and replace it afterward:

```
C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS
```