# How to quickly remove all WMS-Services in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I uploaded a lot of WMS-Services in QGIS via a .XML file.

[image]

When I modify the .XML file, for instance delete a couple of Services or add new ones, my changes are not changed in QGIS.

As an alternative I would like to just delete all of them and upload my new .XML file but I don't find the option to delete all at once. I don't just want to delete one by one.

Where are my services saved and how can I delete all of them at once?

I'm using QGIS 3.4

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: The following may help (not sure about Windows for QGIS 3) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329886/where-does-qgis-store-the-list-of-server-connections-wfs

Comment: Connections are saved into QGIS3.ini file also on Windows. The path is `[APPDATA]\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS` and you can check from Options - System - Current environment variables what is APPDATA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the QGIS Python console and execute the following to clean all the WMS entries (cross platform, so no need to touch ini files wether on Windows, Linux or Mac OS)

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings
settings = QSettings()

settings.beginGroup('qgis/connections-wms')
settings.remove("")
settings.allKeys()
settings.endGroup()
iface.reloadConnections()
```